# (When) is it better to enlarge CosmosDb partitions to avoid cross-partition queries?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, database-partitioning

It's clear from documentation and other CosmosDb articles that smaller partitions have many benefits, but also that cross-partition queries come at a greater cost. So is it wise to broaden partitions to avoid these cross-partition queries?

It may help to have an example. Suppose your container has documents representing cities. Among other fields, each document has a `country`, a `region`, and a `name`. You *could* partition by `country` so that country-wide queries can focus on one partition. But then smaller reads (e.g., a single region or a handful of cities by name) have a larger partition to look through. Is that a good trade-off?

Obviously the specifics will vary based on which queries are needed more often and the only smart way to optimize is after measuring. But generally speaking, **is the additional cost of a cross-partition query significant enough to justify the use of bigger partitions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your data is <50GB then it matters much less as all of your data (inside 20GB logical partitions) will be sitting on a single physical partition. Cross partition queries get increasingly more expensive as the size of your collection grows. The more physical partitions a query has to traverse to serve the results, the higher the RU/s cost and the higher the latency.

Comment: After some time to toss the idea around, let me confirm: when the container is large enough to span multiple physical partitions, a larger logical partition is a sensible way to avoid cross-partition queries - which get expensive fast. For small containers, it's less relevant and so larger partitions are still okay. Keeping in mind of course that it's always best to look at actual usage and adjust to fit.

Comment: Try not to think in terms of designing for how large your partitions will be. The key thing to keep in mind is if your design forces you to serve cross partition queries with high concurrency then your database will not scale. A database like Cosmos can provide infinite scale because it scales out across a cluster of machines. But if you have to touch each on of those machines to handle high volume queries you are designed to be efficient. I did a presentation on this recently, I would watch this video if you are new to Cosmos, https://youtu.be/3gEytt-Jops